# NodeJS node-steam crashing from crypto error

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam

I am working on a steam bot and it keeps crashing with the error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/steam/node_modules/steam-crypto/index.js:6
  var cryptedSessionKey = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, sessionKey);
                                 ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'publicEncrypt'
    at Object.exports.generateSessionKey (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/steam/node_modules/steam-crypto/index.js:6:34)
    at SteamClient.handlers.(anonymous function) (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:216:44)
    at SteamClient._netMsgReceived (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:157:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Connection._readPacket (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/steam/lib/connection.js:50:8)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
    at Connection.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
```

In the README.md for node-steam on [GitHub](https://github.com/seishun/node-steam#installation) it says that only NodeJS 4.1.1 and above is supported. I have tested on v4.1.1 as well as v4.2.2 and still get this error. How can I fix this?

EDIT: Also tested with the latest version (v5.1.0) of Node with no luck.

The code I have currently is the same as the example at the GitHub link provided which I have only changed variables used to login to steam.

Comment: You are omitting the actual code, the error reflects a possible scoping issue from an iterative loop or async stream read.

Comment: jas, the code is the same as the example on the GitHub which is at https://github.com/seishun/node-steam/blob/master/example.js